# Don't know where to install the modules

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm-install

I am currently getting to grips with angular using a book, currently on testing. So I have the tutorial project folder set up in localhost C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\learningangular. So I installed nodejs  as the book instructs and from then on I don't know where to install the modules and dependencies - Karma, Jasmine, Angular-mock...... and what needs to go where because the book doesn't really help with that in the chapter. Do I have to move the tutorial project folder from localhost to nodejs folder which is located in the C:\Program Files\nodejs and also install the modules and dependencies there? Or can I still work from localhost. Also how does one change the npm install destination folder when using the console?

Answer (score 0):

You use the project folder and install the local packages there. The [NPM Getting Started](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm) will give you the missing information from your book you need to get up and running.